# How to update the Docker image of running AWS ECS FARGATE task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to update my docker image in existing running AWS ECS FARGATE task. 
I could have go with new revision but when I run that task inside cluster, it is creating new public IP address.

I can't change my existing public IP. I only want to update my docker image of running task.
What could be the possible solution ?

Comment: EIP is not yet supported for ECS Fargate task as of now.  This issue is raised in the Containers Road Map here - https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/311 - you might want to add your vote and use-case there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately if you're running the container as a publicly routable container it will always update the public IP address of the container whenever you update the task definition.

There is currently no support for elastic IP addresses in Fargate, which would be the solution you're looking for.

I would suggest if keeping the IP address is required that you look at re architecting your solution to the following:

- Public facing Network Load Balancer with a static IP address
- Fargate containers register to a target group of the Network Load Balancer.

Remember that if you had any kind of failure at the moment this might also cause your container to lose its IP address.